# Webpack modules usage from an html page

Tags: javascript, webpack, amd

i'm trying to use webpack to bundle a bunch of AMD modules.

Before, i used r.js bundler to bundle all my AMD modules in a huge bundle.js.

I used requirejs to get a dependency and using in it my html page:

```
<script>
    require(["foolib"], function (foolib) {
        foolib.foo();
    });
</script
```

But with webpack, i failed to reproduce the same behaviour.

The requirejs module loader can work with AMD modules but webpack generates a bundle with a different syntax that i don't understand.

How can i get my "foolib" module to use its functionalities in my page ?

Comment: Did you try to put all the AMD modules file in the entry as a Array. Like `{entry: main:[//you files]}`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sample project which answers perfectly this question: [multi-part-library](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library)